# maven checkstyle plugin creates an output file and fails checking it

Tags: maven, checkstyle

I have a question regarding the maven checkstyle plugin. The problem is that it creates an output file and fails because that file does end with new line (which the plugin is supposed to check for):

```
[ERROR] target/checkstyle-result.xml:[0] (misc) NewlineAtEndOfFile: File does not end with a newline.
```

I tried to exclude the target directory from that plugin with:

```
<properties>
        <checkstyle.excludes>**/target/**</checkstyle.excludes>
</properties>
```

but that does not do anything.

The plugin itself is configured in the parent pom.xml file, so I don't have any control over it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and figured it out. The problems with your rule (and mine before) are the following:

- `**/target/**` does not match the file `target/checkstyle-result.xml`. A better approach would be `**/target/**/*`
- Since your XML is not source code but a resource, you should use the [`checkstyle.resourceExcludes`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html#resourceExcludes) property instead.